# VBA: Format MS Word text

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to format text of multiple words. So far, the code below will only allow me to format the font of one word. What do I need to add / delete in order to have as many words as I input be formatted?

Cheers!

```
Sub FnFindAndFormat()

    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim intParaCount
    Dim objParagraph
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\USERPATH")
    objWord.Visible = True
    intParaCount = objDoc.Paragraphs.Count

    Set objParagraph = objDoc.Paragraphs(1).range
    objParagraph.Find.Text = "deal"

    Do
        objParagraph.Find.Execute
        If objParagraph.Find.Found Then
            objParagraph.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            objParagraph.Font.Size = 20
            objParagraph.Font.Bold = True
            objParagraph.Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
        End If


    Loop While objParagraph.Find.Found

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are the other words stored? I can only see `deal`.

Comment: they are not stored anywhere, I can not add more words to this without the code running into an error

Comment: What are the other words? Can you name a few. I would like to test it before I post the code

Comment: contract, sign, award

Comment: Ok give me 15 mins to create a sample and test it

Comment: Quick question. If you are doing this from word then why are you latebinding with MS Word?

Comment: I want to move it to excel eventually

Comment: In that case, pick the 2nd code from the answer below ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say your word document looks like this

[image]

Since I am not sure whether you are doing this from `Word-VBA` or from some other application like say `Excel-VBA` so I am including both methods.

Now if you are doing this from `Word-VBA` then you do not need to LateBind with it. Use this simple code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oDoc As Document
    Dim MyAr() As String, strToFind As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> This holds your search words
    strToFind = "deal,contract, sign, award"

    '~~> Create an array of text to be found
    MyAr = Split(strToFind, ",")

    '~~> Open the relevant word document
    Set oDoc = Documents.Open("C:\Sample.docx")

    '~~> Loop through the array to get the seacrh text
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = MyAr(i)
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute

            '~~> Change the attributes
            Do Until .Found = False
                With Selection.Font
                    .Name = "Times New Roman"
                    .Size = 20
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
                End With
                Selection.Find.Execute
            Loop
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

However if you are doing from say `Excel-VBA` then use this

```
Const wdFindContinue = 1

Sub FnFindAndFormat()
    Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object, Rng As Object
    Dim MyAr() As String, strToFind As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> This holds your search words
    strToFind = "deal,contract, sign, award"

    '~~> Create an array of text to be found
    MyAr = Split(strToFind, ",")

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    '~~> Open the relevant word document
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Sample.docx")

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set Rng = objWord.Selection

    '~~> Loop through the array to get the seacrh text
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        With Rng.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = MyAr(i)
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Execute

            Set Rng = objWord.Selection

            '~~> Change the attributes
            Do Until .Found = False
                With Rng.Font
                    .Name = "Times New Roman"
                    .Size = 20
                    .Bold = True
                    .Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
                End With
                Rng.Find.Execute
            Loop
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Search Excel VBA Help for `Application.GetOpenFileName` :) BTW, if you have a different question then it has to go into a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm for me:

```
Public Sub Find_some_text()

'setting objects
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objSelection

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("H:\Test.docx")

'set visibility
objWord.Visible = True

'set array of words to format
words_list = Array("Findme_1", "Findme_2", "etc")

'formatting text
For Each w In words_list
    Set Frange = objDoc.Range
    Frange.Find.Text = w
    Do
      Frange.Find.Execute
      If Frange.Find.Found Then
         Frange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
         Frange.Font.Size = 20
         Frange.Font.Bold = True
         Frange.Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
      End If
    Loop While Frange.Find.Found
Next

'de-set visibility
objWord.Visible = False

'saving (optional)
objDoc.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
For Each w In words_list
    Set Frange = objDoc.Range
    Frange.Find.Text = w
    Do
      Frange.Find.Execute
      If Frange.Find.Found Then
         Frange.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
         Frange.Font.Size = 20
         Frange.Font.Bold = True
         Frange.Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
      End If
    Loop While Frange.Find.Found
Next
```

is inefficient. Try:

```
With objDoc.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  With .Replacement
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^&"
    With .Font
      .Name = "Times New Roman"
      .Size = 20
      .Bold = True
      .Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
    End With
  End With
  .Format = True
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = 1 'wdFindContinue
  For Each w In words_list
    .Text = w
    .Execute Replace:=2 'wdReplaceAll
  Next
End With
```